# Google Play UI language vs review language - what's happening here?

Tags: google-play-store, languages, app-ratings

I'm Polish, in Poland, but use English for the interface. I posted a review on a Polish app (in Polish, of course)... and it's not visible to people with Polish UI language selected.
I've tried changing the language in Google Play to Polish, deleting the review, and writing it again. Still no change.
What must I do to make my comment visible in Polish?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add &hl=pl to the end of the URL.

(So it becomes https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.touchtype.swiftkey&hl=pl )

This will force the Play store to change to Polish entirely, and display the Polish version of the site, not just the translation. (Works for all Google sites, and all languages) It will remain in Polish until you close the page or tab.